# Unsure what the rep() is doing in a line of code in R

Tags: r

I am extremely new to R and programming in general so forgive my likely broad question.

Here is the particular line of code I am unsure of:

```
layout(matrix(rep(c(1,1,2), 2), ncol=2))
```

What is `rep()` doing? I am trying to plot multiple graphs and this is all the code being used:

```
par(mfcol=c(2,1), mar=c(4,4,2,2))
layout(matrix(rep(c(1,1,2), 2), ncol=2)
hist(bDist, xlab="", main="bootstrap distribution")
boxplot(bDist, xlab="difference between median male and female pulse rate (beats/min)", horizontal=T)
```

Comment: `rep` is just replicating the vector c(1, 1, 2) to `c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `layout` requires the input as a `matrix`.  The `rep` in the post is just replicating the `vector` 'n' times. If we don't use `rep`, it would result in a 2 x2 matrix with a length warning

```
matrix(c(1,1,2), ncol=2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    1
```

With `rep`, it creates a `length` of 6 and the `matrix` with 2 columns have 3 rows

```
matrix(rep(c(1,1,2), 2), ncol=2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    1    1
#[3,]    2    2
```

Comment: Awesome that makes sense thank you very much akrun! So, essentially, this is being done to 'increase' the size of the histogram relative to the boxplot in the chart area?

Comment: @m33 yes, it is just to replicate that values